# Ant Design Form.getFieldsError always returning empty errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, antd

I am having a simple AntD Form with some field validation. I am expecting the error array to hold for example the required error when calling the getFieldsError function. But the returned error array is always empty eventhough when the error is shown inline in the UI.

```
        const [form] = Form.useForm();

        <Form className={otherProps.className} form={form}>
            <Form.Item
              name="name"
              rules={[
                { required: true, message: 'A name is required!' },
                () => ({
                  validator(_, value) {
                    if (!!items.find((item: Item) => item.name === value)) {
                      return Promise.reject(new Error('The name must be unique!'));
                    }
                    return Promise.resolve();
                  },
                }),
              ]}
              initialValue={itemForm.item.name}
            >
              <Input
                value={itemForm.item.name}
                placeholder="Item name"
                onChange={(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                  form.setFieldsValue({ name: event.target.value });
                  console.log(form.getFieldsError());
                }}
              />
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>
```

Comment: Okay I found my mistake: the errors are set asynchron so right after setting the value the error is not available, thats why the console log does not represent that error at the time.